# Image Button src image gone after inflating xml into LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, android-imagebutton

I have an XML with roughly the following layout:

```
<merge>
    <LinearLayout (horizontal)>
        <ImageButton/>
        <ImageButton/>
        <ImageButton/>
    <LinearLayout/>

    <TextView/>
<merge/>
```

When I inflate the XML into a custom vertical Linear Layout, everything goes as expected. The sizes of each item are correct and the textView shows up just fine.

But the ImageButtons are completely transparent now and have no images in them despite me specifying the source when I run my app in the emulator. In the Design view of the XML editor, my ImageButtons have their source images and look fine. Here's how each ImageButton I have roughly looked like in XML:

```
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/endBtn"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:tint="@color/white"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_close_black_24dp" />
```

I'm inflating the view with the following code in my custom `LinearLayout` view class:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.game_controls_view, this, true);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `tint` color is messing with the `src` drawable here. I would suggest removing the `tint` color and check if the image is showing now.

If that does not work, try removing `app:srcCompat` and use `tools:srcCompat` only for the `ImageButton` as follows.

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/endBtn"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:elevation="12dp"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but it still is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are using vector drawable using app:srcCompact.so you need to add this line to your build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
    ...

    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true // This line here
}
```

The second option is to use android:src to refer to vector drawables.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this
<ImageButton android:id="@+id/endBtn"
        android:layout_width="36dp"
        android:layout_height="36dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0w8aj.png
```